# Load files from URL in service

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I try to load photos in  Service.
This method invoke in onStartCommand()

```
private void loadPhotos() {
    //add Subscription in CompositeSubscription
    mSubscription.add(Utils.getQueryObserver(this, DataProvider.CONTENT_TASKS_URI, null, LoadingTask.COLUMN_ISMAIN + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(1)}, null)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
             //create list of tasks
            .map(this::createTasks)
             //merge with another part of tasks
            .mergeWith(Utils.getQueryObserver(this, DataProvider.CONTENT_TASKS_URI, null, LoadingTask.COLUMN_ISMAIN + " = ?",
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(0)}, null)
                    .map(this::createTasks))

            .flatMap(Observable::from)
            // exception here
            .subscribe(this::writeFile,
                    Throwable::getCause,
                    //stop service 
                    this::stopSelf));

}
```

but if I shut down the application, I receive an exception:

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Utils.getQueryObserver() method:

```
 public static Observable<Cursor> getQueryObserver(Context context, Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String order) {
    return Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(context.getContentResolver()
            .query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, order)));
}
```

> .flatMap(Observable::from)

returned list of task, Every task contains URL of image, after that in

> writeFile()

method I call OKHTTP request for each url in turn.

Comment: Use a background thread for any network call.

Comment: how to implement it? Do you have any example?

Comment: Thanks, .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) help me

Comment: new Thread(new Runnable(...)).start(); ??